# Recursive Function for Counting Palindromes

Tags: python, function, recursion

I know that this question has been asked quite a bit, but the issue I have is slightly different. This assignment requires me to not verify if a string is a palindrome - but to verify how many palindromes are in one string (return as an 'int'). This was supposed to be done both using an iterative function & a recursive function, but I'm having trouble with the recursive part :(

For reference, here is my code for the iterative function:

```
def iterativePalindrome(str, n): 
    allPalindromes = [[0 for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)] 
    verify = [[False for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)]
  
    for i in range(n): 
        verify[i][i] = True

    for i in range(n - 1): 
        if (str[i] == str[i + 1]): 
            verify[i][i + 1] = True
            allPalindromes[i][i + 1] = 1
  
    for iterativeGap in range(2, n): 
        for start in range(n - iterativeGap): 
            end = iterativeGap + start; 

            if (str[start] == str[end] and verify[start + 1][end - 1]): 
                verify[start][end] = True
 
            if (verify[start][end] == True): 
                allPalindromes[start][end] = (allPalindromes[start][end - 1] + allPalindromes[start + 1][end] + 1 - allPalindromes[start + 1][end - 1]) 
            else: 
                allPalindromes[start][end] = (allPalindromes[start][end - 1] + allPalindromes[start + 1][end] - allPalindromes[start + 1][end - 1]) 

    return allPalindromes[0][n - 1]
```

I'm just having a difficult time regarding converting this into a recursive function. Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide what you have written so far

Comment: Also, give examples of input and expected results.

Comment: To be honest I don't really have anything written so far except for the iterative version to solving this problem ;-; But, I can provide examples of inputs and expected results! The example we were given in class was "kayak", and the expected result for the number of palindromes in this string is '2' ! I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I made it! take a look at my recursion implementation which finds all the palindromes in string, in my opinion it is not the most clean way to solve it (any suggestions to make it simpler will be more than welcome), feel free to ask whatever not clear for you:

```
found = []
def count_palindrome(m_str, start, end, orig_len):
    if len(m_str)<2:
        return
    elif m_str == m_str[::-1]:
        if (start, end) not in found:
            found.append((start, end))
            if len(m_str)<orig_len:
                return
    counter = count_palindrome(m_str[:-1], start, end-1,  orig_len)
    counter = count_palindrome(m_str[1:], start+1, end, orig_len)

str_to_work_on = "acac"
count_palindrome(str_to_work_on, 0, len(str_to_work_on), len(str_to_work_on))
for indices in found:
    print(str_to_work_on[indices[0]:indices[1]])
```

output:

```
aca
cac

# I tried it on more complex examples as well and it seems to work fine for my eyes,
# try to challenge it by giving extra complex examples and examine the results.
# let me know if you find something which not work as you expect
```

Comment: This works really well for the palindromes I was provided (e.g. kayak) !! I was just wondering if there was a way to convert the number of palindromes printed within the string as an integer? Either way, your help was super appreciated!

Comment: `len(found)` is the answer as integer. Is that what you mean?

Comment: OMG YES THIS IS PERFECT !! completely forgot about the length feature in python.. thank you so much ;;

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for recursion but it's computing some values again which can be overcome by dynamic programming(memoization). Any suggestion would be appreciated.
So, here is the pseudo-code for recursion.

```
Check whether the string from 'start' index to 'end' index is a palindrome if yes -> inc. the answer and then
recursively check for other strings by removing first and last character from the current string

    import numpy as np
    #initializing dp array with zeros
    dp = np.zeros(shape = (len(st) , len(st))

    def CountPalindromes(st , start, end):
        if(dp[start][end] == 1): return 0
        flag = checkIfTheStringIsPalindrome(st , start, end)
        ans = 0
        if(flag): ans = 1
        dp[start][end] = 1
        if(start < end):
            return ans + CountPalindromes(st , start, end-1) + CountPalindromes(st , start+1 , end)
        else: return ans


     answer = CountPalindromes(st , 0 , len(st)-1)
     print(answer)
```

In the above code, many strings will be rechecked, and which will increase the count, for solving that, dp array is used to keep track of already calculated sub-problems